# ASP.NET prevent double clicking

Tags: jquery, asp.net, double-click

I've looked at this before and found javascript that works for me with Google Chrome, Firefox, and IE when I test it but it seems randomly (or browser specific) it doesn't work.  I need a solution that does work.

This is what I'm currently using with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.Once").one("click", function () {
        $(this).click(function () { return false; });
    });
});
```

I add the class "Once" to buttons I want to make sure aren't clicked more than once.  Again, It always works properly for me but for some users it doesn't do anything at all.  Is there a better alternative solution that always works?

Update: These are ASP.NET LinkButtons.

Update 6/18:
I've gotten more info from two users who keeps having this problem.

One says he hits the button once and the screen flashes so he leaves the page and comes back to it and hits the button again which causes it to post twice automatically.

The other claims he hits a different button which causes this button to postback twice automatically.  I looked at the code and there's nothing wrong with that button.

The only thing I can think of is a caching problem or maybe hitting the button before the page finishes loading.  I haven't been able to reproduce the problem and one of them is using the exact same browser I use.

Comment: When you say "double clicking", do you mean clicking an element more than once, ever - or the UI gesture "double-click"?

Comment: Clicking the button multiple times.  Some people are double clickers.  It's an ASP.NET LinkButton.  I probably should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is for a form post, then you can disable all submit buttons on submit with:

```
$('#someForm').submit(function(){
    $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Or are they allowed to click more than once, but only after some time has elapsed?

There are scenarios where one() fails - see the comments on 
http://api.jquery.com/one/
Any idea if its a browser compat issue with your users or jQuery not loading?

EDIT:
Just found out this is a linkbutton. in that case try

```
$('#yourClientIdForYourLinkButton').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

or using the clientid directly something like

```
$('#<%=linkButton.ClientId%>').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: It's a LinkButton, which is a hyperlink.  I should have mentioned that.  This doesn't stop it.

Comment: in that case you will need to attach on onclick event - see my edit

Answer (score 2):

I have tried many options with JQuery but this is how I solved after writing a simple code in c#:

.aspx page:

Now you add this to your code behind in Page_Load:

```
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

         ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

         ButtonID.Attributes.Add("onClick", "this.disabled=true;" +    cs.GetPostBackEventReference(ButtonID, "").ToString());

       }
```

and the last thing:

```
      protected void ButtonID_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
      {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            //rest of your code

      }
```

Hope this helps!

**Update on post:**

Using JavaScript you can stop form submission at client side event of button click, when it happens for second time

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var isSubmitted = false;

      function preventMultipleSubmissions() {

      if (!isSubmitted) {

         $('#<%=btnSubmit.ClientID %>').val('Submitting.. Plz Wait..');

        isSubmitted = true;

        return true;

      }

      else {

        return false;

      }

    }

    </script>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="return preventMultipleSubmissions();"  OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"  />
```

Or you can do it in the backend on Postback:

```
btnSubmit.Attributes.Add("onclick", " this.disabled = true; " + ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnSubmit, null) + ";");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the existing link and place some text afterwards that alerts that user that the page is loading.

```
<asp:LinkButton CssClass="Once" runat="server">Button</asp:LinkButton>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $("a.Once").one("click", function (event)
        {
            $(this).hide().after("Please wait while we load your page...");
        });
    });

</script>
```

Also, consider adding code server side. You can never count on JavaScript being enabled.

EDIT: Answer 2.0

Comment: It's actually an ASP.NET LinkButton so it has an href=.  Yesterday I changed the href value to # but I didn't like the result of that.  Now that I think about it I should have changed it to: javascript:void(0);

Comment: I think jQuery is the problem.  Instead of disable I changed the href to javascript:void(0); and noticed one time I hit the button it didn't do anything, like it was already void, even though it shouldn't have been.  The form never submitted.  Do you have server side code for .NET to prevent it?

Comment: If you are using the LinkButton, you are in WebForms. You can store a value in the ViewState when the user clicks the button. ViewState["buttonId_clicked"] = true. Then you can check it in the LinkButton click event. If that ViewState value is true, don't execute the logic. It's not ideal, but a way to handle it.
Thinking about your issue, jQuery attaches an additional event, it does not replace the existing event. I'll update the code to reflect.

Comment: None of these ideas are working.  Randomly the click event is firing twice at literally the exact same time.  The code is executing twice.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I may have misunderstood your original question. Please see if my updated answer assists you!

Comment: Your updated answer completely solved my double click issue on my .NET page! Thank you, Fammy

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your desire here. One option is to disable the anchor tag after it is clicked. This should be something that works across all browsers.

Another option that I have seen used is to hide the item in question, ala http://www.ilovecolors.com.ar/avoid-double-click-jquery/, but that may be overkill for what you are attempting.

Comment: Yesterday I changed the href to # and didn't like what happened as a result of that.  I should probably just remove the href tag all together?  Having nothing happen when it's clicked the second time is preferred.