# Prevent to call the controller method more times when click submit button in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my mvc application, all the validations of applicant registration were done in the server side. I want to control the multiple records creating in the database for one specific email. But in the DB, there is no unique key for the email filed. Also, my lead doesn't like to change the server side coding (to use a lock or mutex). So i want to mange this situation from js function. I have an idea to do this using a timer. from the first click, I start a time and measure the time to the 2nd click and it is less than 1/2 of second, prevent the submit event. Please can u help me to do this?

Thanks,
Nuwan

Comment: i dint understand you question properly but as far as i understood, why dont you disable the submit button once its click for certain period ?

Comment: I tried it too. it is redirecting to an empty page when I set disabled. I checked so many ways. according to the existing development, all techniques were failed. That's why I plan to do this via a timer.

Comment: to make my understanding clear, can you clarify my understanding ? you have a form .. and you dont want a user to submit that button for certain period of time ? is it ?

Comment: Correct. Dont want a user to submit that button for certain period of time after submit one time.

Comment: usually after submitting the form..what happens ? it will show the same page again or redirect to some other page?

Comment: redirect to a another page.

Comment: so when page is redirecting to another page after submitting..how can a user submit it again ? i am just trying to understand the scenario more

Comment: in MVC, it return to another view from the controller method. This issue is happening at the initial state when the form submit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET prevent double clicking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284861/asp-net-prevent-double-clicking)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you disable the button after clicking it using Jquery (if it is on a postback to redirect to another page) this will prevent the user to have the same event several times.